# is there a api to see most recent listings on steam market

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steambot

is there a api i can use to see new steam listings for specific csgo items.

i know there is this api i can use to see some information

https://steamcommunity.com/market/priceoverview/?appid=730&currency=21&market_hash_name=(name)
i use this for getting things like stock and price for example

but is there a specific API i can use to get new listings and see specific details on new listings or get a inspect link for each item.